# AdminDirectory.Groups.aliases.list undefined

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use google api with google scripts.
I can get data from google apps for example by:
var result = AdminDirectory.Groups.get(OptionalArgs); 
but when i try to do the same with:
var result = AdminDirectory.Groups.aliases.list(OptionalArgs);
I receive
TypeError: Cannot call method "list" of undefined
How can I get and update list of google apps groups aliases using google scripts?
What am I doing wrong with this sample?

Answer (score 0):

The alias property should be capitalised.

```
var result = AdminDirectory.Groups.Aliases.list(OptionalArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you already have done and what hasn't been done, I suggest that you please check and ensure that you [enable advance services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) before use and as described in the [API's prerequisites documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites), the Admin SDK must also be enabled on your domain.

And, to [retrieve all group aliases](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_group_aliases),

> use the following `GET` request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing). The `groupKey` can be the group's primary email address, the group's unique id, or any of the group aliases' emails. For the request and response properties, see the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups):
>
> `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/aliases`

Lastly, as also noted, these are editable group aliases in the account's primary domain or subdomains. For group aliases outside of the account, see the [group's nonEditableAliases property](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups#nonEditableAliases).

Reading through [Google Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script) might also help.